# Issue with the Regex in UK Post Code validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a certain issue in defining the regex for UK postal code. I have made the regex which is in accordance with the client requirement, which is working fine in the [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) test. but when I tried to test the same in the javascript i had the situation in which it is accepting one more letter in the last.

**RULE :** part before space can have 2/3/4 characters but 1st should be numeric. and part in the right can only have 3 characters in which 1st should be number and other two must be letters.

**Regex:** :

```
 /^[A-Za-z](([A-Za-z]|[0-9]){1,2})?([A-Za-z]|[0-9]) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2}/g
```

and my **javascript Code** (through which I am checking it):

```
 var str = /^[A-Za-z](([A-Za-z]|[0-9]){1,2})?([A-Za-z]|[0-9]) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2}/g ;
 var res = str.test($scope.pincode);
```

**ISSUE :** the valid formats are :

A12 1ES
A122 1ES
ASD 1RD

**but it is also accepting**

A12 1ESD

can someone help me in the same?

Comment: Add `$` at the end, use [`/^[A-Za-z](([A-Za-z]|[0-9]){1,2})?([A-Za-z]|[0-9]) [0-9][A-Za-z]{2}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/G0Gn8P/1)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew it worked :)